# selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation() is not working

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm stuck in one of the confirmation message. Below is the code.

`boolean bFlag = selenium.isConfirmationPresent();` // which gives bFlag= false

```
selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();
selenium.click("//input[@value='Approve']");
```

// On clicking Approve button confirmation messasge is displayed.
`boolean Flag = selenium.isConfirmationPresent();` // Which gives flag= true

Selenium is unable to click OK in the confirmation. I'm unable to continue with further coding.  Nun of the selenium commands is working after clicking on approve button.

Can any one help me on this

Regards

Comment: hi, could you please be more elaborate, on your question..its not clear...(pls. edit it, with proper formatting) ..one possible soln., pls. try to select the window, where the confirmation message comes..and then try to click on Ok, manually once...

Comment: boolean bFlag = selenium.isConfirmationPresent(); selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation(); 
selenium.click("//input[@value='Approve']");
boolean Flag = selenium.isConfirmationPresent(); 

Above is the code. After clicking on Approve button. if i check for confirmation flag is showing me true. I can not spy the confirmation through firebug.
 When i click button through script confirmation will not be displayed. 
IF i click the button manually confirmation will be displayed.

Comment: So, if I get it right, when you give, selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation(), the OK button is not clicked and the script is failing, but if you say, selenium.selectWindow("name1");selenium.click("Ok"); you are able to click on the button and proceed with further testing...??

Comment: Why can't you give, selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation(), after, the selenium.click("Approve") event??

Answer (score 1):

I only have a reference to a rather old piece of documentation, but I guess what is said there is still true
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#chooseOkOnNextConfirmation

> every time a confirmation comes up, you must consume it with a corresponding getConfirmation, or else the next selenium operation will fail.

So your code should look like this:

```
selenium.chooseOkOnNextConfirmation();
selenium.click("//input[@value='Approve']");
String confirmation = selenium.getConfirmation();
assertEquals("expected text of confirmation", confirmation); // check content of confirmation, optional
// now continue with more selenium commands
```